# Python SMTP server that can receive MIME attachment

Tags: python, smtp, mime

I want to implement a simple email server just like amazon kindle mail server does for ebook convert.
User mail me doc as attachment. Mail server will retrieve and store those doc. Maybe response back to sender about the convert result, simply success or failure. 
I want to implement this in Python. Looking into the built in SMTPServer class, it only be able to handle RFC2822 formatted message body.

Is there anyway to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Yes I'm sure there is a way to achieve it. Do you have another question perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

"it only be able to handle RFC2822 formatted message body. " - thats enough for what you are trying to achieve. MIME attachments are covered in RFC 2822 extensions. the python email library contains various functions to walk through the message payload and extract attachments

Answer (score 1):

You could checkout [Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/), which is a framework + SMTP server developing email apps.